# converting C# method to Java(Android Studio)

Tags: java, c#, android-studio

here is the code of C# which i am trying to convert

```
ArrayList.BinarySearch(Object, IComparer)
```

what it does is to comparer a node class object with a compare class object and returns -1, 0 or positive integer.
i have searched a lot and tried to convert it in java but could not do so. i'll need a method, instructions, library or anything that could help me achieve it.

class Class1
    {

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ArrayList SolutionPathList = new ArrayList();

        //Create a node containing the goal state node_goal
        Node node_goal = new Node(null,null,1,15,15);

        //Create a node containing the start state node_start
        Node node_start = new Node(null,node_goal,1,0,0);


        //Create OPEN and CLOSED list
        SortedCostNodeList OPEN = new SortedCostNodeList ();
        SortedCostNodeList CLOSED = new SortedCostNodeList ();


        //Put node_start on the OPEN list
        OPEN.push (node_start);
        }
```

SortedNode class is:

```
 public class SortedCostNodeList
{
    ArrayList _list;
    NodeComparer _nodeComparer;
 public SortedCostNodeList()
    {
        _list = new ArrayList ();
        _nodeComparer = new NodeComparer ();
    }
  public int push (Node n)
    {

        int k = _list.BinarySearch (n,_nodeComparer);

        if (k==-1) // no element
            _list.Insert (0,n);
        else if (k<0) // find location by complement
        {
            k=~k;
            _list.Insert (k,n);
        }
        else if (k>=0)
            _list.Insert (k,n);

        return k;
    }
```

and nodecomparer class is:

```
  public class NodeComparer:IComparer
{
    public NodeComparer()
    {

    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return ((Node)x).totalCost -  ((Node) y).totalCost ;
    }
}
```

i am unable to implement this piece of code
       //int k = _list.BinarySearch (n,_nodeComparer);

any help?

Comment: The `BinarySearch` method does precisely what it suggests: utilizes a binary search algorithm to locate a specified object. You can easily [implement the method yourself](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/), or you can always just use a regular iterative search if performance isn't a great concern. (Keep in mind that a binary search is only effective on sorted collections.)

Comment: As a side note, I don't know if you came up with these C# methods yourself, but you shouldn't be using `ArrayList` in C# anymore. It was made obsolete a long time ago in favor of the generic `List`, which outside of applications specifically for dealing with legacy systems is preferable in every regard. (To clarify though, I'm talking about C#. The Java `ArrayList` is a lot like the C# `List`, and from what I remember is still perfectly fine to use.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(T[],%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)) to perform binary search on an array of Object.

I have created a sample program. Hope it helps.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
class Node {
    private long totalCost;
}

public class StackOverFlow {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        final List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Node(10));
        list.add(new Node(20));
        list.add(new Node(30));
        list.add(new Node(40));
        list.add(new Node(50));
        list.add(new Node(60));
        list.add(new Node(70));

        final Node searchKey = new Node(60);
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(list.toArray(new Node[list.size()]), searchKey, new Comparator<Node>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
                return (int) (o1.getTotalCost() - o2.getTotalCost());
            }
        });

        System.out.print("Found at " + index);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Try this

```
class NodeComparator implements Comparator<Node> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
        return (int) (o1.getTotalCost() - o2.getTotalCost());
    }
}

class SortedCostNodeList {
    ArrayList<Node> list;
    NodeComparator nodeCompartor;

    public SortedCostNodeList() {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
        this.nodeCompartor = new NodeComparator();
    }

    public int push(Node n) {

        int k = Arrays.binarySearch(this.list.toArray(new Node[list.size()]), n, this.nodeCompartor);

        if (k == -1) // no element
            this.list.add(0, n);
        else if (k < 0) // find location by complement
        {
            k = ~k;
            this.list.add(k, n);
        } else if (k >= 0)
            this.list.add(k, n);

        return k;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Still no progress. i am using it like this but its saying illegal 3rd parameter.
      int k = Arrays.binarySearch(list.toArray(new Node[list.size()]), start, new Comparator<Node>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
                return (int) (o1.gettotalCost() - o2.gettotalCost());
            }
        });

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm